# Network reputation graph becomes nervous when clicking quickly, backs away slowly

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

On the [network reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c?tab=reputation), when you either double-click on the legend or click quickly<sup>1</sup>, the graph lines seem sketched out by this, and move to the left, away from the action (also, they don't always all move the same distance, the one you're clicking on seems to become misaligned from the rest):

[image]

I can make this happen on:

- Chrome 58, Windows (also in an incognito tab, also confirmed on OS X)
- Firefox 53, Windows
- IE 11, Windows
- Chrome Whatever, Android

Also, while the graph lines' trust can be earned back by clicking slowly (whereupon they will return to calmly grazing on the legend's grassy field), as Laurel noticed in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296884/network-reputation-graph-becomes-nervous-when-clicking-quickly-backs-away-slowl?noredirect=1#comment963231_296884), some of the X axis labels are far more timid, and e.g. 2013 and earlier simply run away entirely.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Say "click quickly" five times fast. I could barely *type* it.</sup>

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested it on Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge and only managed to reproduce it on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Chrome 58, Windows

Comment: I can also make it happen on Android Chrome, although it's tough to get the timing right to not trigger zoom.

Comment: That's strange. I'm also using Chrome 58 on Windows and I can't manage to reproduce it with Chrome. For me, clicking just selects the text without changing anything on the graph.

Comment: Also happens for me on Firefox 53 and IE11.

Comment: This also happens on Chrome (58) for Mac. Also, looking at your gif, what happened to 2013?! I think there's another bug here.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even catch that.