# Reputation graph bug + JS error message

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

#### The bug

[Reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/1927945/uprego?tab=reputation):
[image]

---

Click the upper line of the legend in other to make it go away, chart is zoomed not only down but also *left*. Notice the red line disappearing from the zoomed chart. Notice yaxis going crazy.
[image]

---

Click the upper line of the legend again in order to make it come back, chart tries to go back to the initial zoom, maybe accomplishes that, I don't know, but lines alignment have changed. Notice yaxis not going completely normal.
[image]

Either the first chart or the third chart are wrong data.

This is Opera 62.0.3331.119.

Can reproduce using Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 and Chromium 47.0.2503.0.

This is macOS 10.14.6.

---

#### How this is different from [Network reputation graph becomes nervous when clicking quickly, backs away slowly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296884) (even likely related to, root cause might be the same but manifestations are different).

If I double click lines in legend, this happens. Dis-adjustment seem to be larger than in my initial report. Notice yaxis acts weirdly in a very similar way to my initial report.

Double click on the legend line corresponding to the blue line when it is enabled.
[image]

Double click on the legend line corresponding to the green line when it is enabled.
[image]

---

**As a notable difference**, what I report causes a JS console *red* message. Contrary wise, [Network reputation graph becomes nervous when clicking quickly, backs away slowly](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296884) **not** (that one doesn't log anything at all when being reproduced):

`highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:12 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "0".`

Corresponding stack:

```
 r @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:12
 attr @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:297
 c.<computed> @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:258
 X.h @ jquery.min.js:3
 X @ jquery.min.js:3
 n.Animation.n.extend.tweeners.* @ jquery.min.js:4
 nb @ jquery.min.js:4
 map @ jquery.min.js:2
 qb @ jquery.min.js:4
 g @ jquery.min.js:4
 dequeue @ jquery.min.js:3
 (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
 each @ jquery.min.js:2
 each @ jquery.min.js:2
 queue @ jquery.min.js:3
 animate @ jquery.min.js:4
 ec @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:257
 animate @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:291
 render @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:72
 (anonymous) @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:61
 o @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:254
 m @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:61
 redraw @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:101
 (anonymous) @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:157
 o @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:254
 h @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:155
 setVisible @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:561
 a @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:190
 Z @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:257
 (anonymous) @ highcharts.js?v=61b1d1bf4167:190
```

Comment: This has been wrongly marked as duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296884 by the system after I clicked "solved my problem!", but I had clicked that after reporting duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324757 and then clicking the "Solved my problem" button was OK, but the system seems to have forgotten the duplicate note I added.

Comment: The title needs improvement. Next time, don't simply say: "There is a small problem", describe what, where,  etc.

Comment: Posting a new bug report just to ask if other bug report is fixed isn't really good idea. That's what we have comments for, on the original report, and chat if you want more people involved.

Comment: Third comment proving true second comment _[chuckles]_.

Comment: To whom may concern, the stack trace was originally posted as a spoiler block on the ignorance of a better way to show a drop down or expandable block - i.e. I guess it's mostly meaningless posted data, and yet I wanted others to know it had been posted (for any use they'd wanted to make, or not).

Comment: The only way I know how to do so is link to an external paste service, but that's not self contained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333496/scale-is-not-updated-correctly-when-changing-zoom-on-reputation-graph