# Scale is not updated correctly when changing zoom on reputation graph

Tags: bug, user-interface, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph

If I zoom somewhere on the reputation graph, the scale is not correctly updated:

Original unzoomed:
[image]

Zoomed (note that the vertical scale has not been correctly updated):
[image]

Reset zoom (the vertical scale is now completely wrong and even out of order; horizontal scale is not correctly updated either):
[image]

I can consistently reproduce this with Firefox 69.0 (64-bit) and with Chrome 77.0.3865.75 on Windows 7 and on Linux.

Comment: Awesome! I think this is a broader, more general, cleaner, better explained case, of [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332645/reputation-graph-bug-js-error-message). :)

Comment: You can check JS raises the same message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Exchange reputation graph: unselecting the top site results in y-axis rescaling mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337364/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-unselecting-the-top-site-results-in-y-axis-resc)

Comment: @mindstormboi It's basically the same question, but it doesn't answer it since there are no answers.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I find it weird that this was marked as a duplicate of the other one (rather than vice versa) when this one preceded it, has more votes, and has an answer posted to it. =/

Comment: whoops, well i guess they still dupes of eachother, since they dont have any official staff answers and only an unofficial workaround which in my opinion is not really an answer but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to fix the display is as follows:

- To **zoom in** to a specific location, and have the **scale perfectly displayed**:

  1. Choose which site(s) you want displayed, see leftmost box in the first image below.
  2. Select a **skinny** box **starting** at the **bottom** of the display, extending upwards to cross the tiny portion that you want to zoom into; only the portion of the visible line (with respect to horizontal) will remain in the zoomed area, the empty space above will be removed and the empty space below will be **partially** removed - the *quality* of the adjustability is preferential to the horizontal
  3. Display is zoomed in and scale is correctly displayed, see rightmost pane, first image

  You can try starting a little higher than the absolute bottom to see how much you can compress the display, there's a limit to how far away from *skinny* (the bottom) that you can go before it triggers a redisplay with a jumbled scale.

[image: First Image - Zoomed in, with perfect scale]

- To **completely reset** the display:

  1. Choose which site(s) you want displayed, see leftmost box in the first image below.
  2. Select a **tiny** box at the **bottom** of the display
  3. Hit the <kbd>Reset Zoom</kbd> button
  4. Display is completely reset, see rightmost pane, second image

[image: Second Image - Complete Reset]

Until the Bug is actually fixed that's the workarounds I've been using to view or take screenshots.