# Stack Exchange reputation graph: unselecting the top site results in y-axis rescaling mess

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, reputation-graph

This is what my [my reputation page](https://stackexchange.com/users/2823463/rebecca-j-stones?tab=reputation) looks like when it first loads:

[image: When the page loads---no problems]

But if we unselect math.SE, we get a y-axis rescaling mess:

[image: After unselecting the top site---y-axis rescaling mess]

I'm using Firefox. I'm in China, so many things involving Google and Imgur are blocked, and I use [Decentraleyes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/decentraleyes/) to stop the browser attempting to load unloadable Google objects.

I'm hoping other users can check whether or not this issue is localized to my system, and if it's not just me, here's the bug report.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and get the same results in North America. Pinch zoom and horizontal axis are hit and miss too. At least the 'Reset Zoom' button and right column work.

Comment: It happens to me too with Chrome on mobile.

Comment: The x-axis scaling ain't any better after you turn off Academia and Chinese as well. Also, confirmed in Chrome 78.0.3904.70 (desktop).

Comment: This is a case where the [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) could *really* have been helpful: You're **only** talking about the y-axis labels, right?

Comment: In contrast, when we [look at reputation (in *Graph Mode*) for a single site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/91818/rebecca-j-stones?tab=reputation&sort=graph) it is coded correctly and [appears reasonably well laid out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d4Fg.jpg); the change of graph style shouldn't be a reason for one to be functional while the other is not.

Comment: @Marco13 [A recent duplicate with freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348700/269301).