# Reputation chart gets misaligned when toggling visibility of certain sites on it

Tags: bug, network-profile, reputation-graph

When I toggle the visibility of certain sites on my reputation chart the reputation milestones (on the left) and the dates get misaligned. To show you what I mean by that here's a few screenshots:

[image: numbersnotinplace]

In this case it's admittedly not much of a problem. You can see that the numbers on the left aren't in place with the lines. Here's another one:

[image: numbers&datessmashedup]

The 400 and 800 are close together when they shouldn't be (ignore the dates in this image).

I don't really think it's browser-related since others seem to have the same problem, but in chrome://version I see the following:

```
Google Chrome  83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision  94f915a8d7c408b09cc7352161ad592299f384d2-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#561}
OS  Windows 10 OS Version 1903 (Build 18362.836)
```

I normally use Chrome in a smaller window, but on a full window it's still happening, even when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> to access complete fullscreen.

On Microsoft Edge I'm still having the same problem:

[image: brokenbroken]

The dates are *very* misaligned and the numbers on the left are indeed misaligned as well.

<sub>You can test this for yourself on [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/18133942/mindstormsboi?tab=reputation) to see if you're having the same problem. Try randomly hiding and showing certain sites on the chart by clicking the color codes on the right.</sub>

Comment: Presumably the same issue as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337364/132874