# Reputation graph axis labels

Tags: bug, reputation, stackexchange.com, network-profile, reputation-graph

When zooming in on a [user's reputation grid in the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), the axis labels are not always calculated or displayed correctly. Here's two examples, first zoomed in and then after resetting zoom:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

And these should be the correct maximum values on my reputation graph:

[image: Correct Values]

Comment: related / duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337364/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-unselecting-the-top-site-results-in-y-axis-resc

Comment: @Luuklag Similar, but in my case it was manual zoom rather than automatic from toggling sites - probably the same root cause on the zoom issue, but surprising it's been a known bug for 2.5 years now without even staff acknowledgement on that bug post...