# Reputation graph labels become misaligned

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

I managed to reproduce this several times, but each time it looks slightly different:

[image: A reputation graph. From top to bottom, the y-axis is labelled "5k", "2k", "4k", "3k", "1k".]
[image: A reputation graph. From top to bottom, the y-axis is labelled "2,500", "1,500", "2,000", "500", ",000". The "2" in "2,000" is partially cut off.]
[image: A reputation graph. The axis labels are in the correct order, but positioned wrong, and some labels are missing. It says "Jan '22" and "Jan '23" where it should say "Jan '23" and "May '23", respectively.]

Reproduction:

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/users/8322029/bbrk24?tab=reputation
2. Click on "Stack Overflow" or "Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange", so that the graph resizes itself.

This isn't browser- or OS-specific: I can reproduce it in Firefox and Edge on Windows 11, and Safari on iOS 16.

Comment: Confirmed on Brave, too.

Comment: Only works when clicking on "Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange". ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Exchange reputation graph: unselecting the top site results in y-axis rescaling mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337364/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-unselecting-the-top-site-results-in-y-axis-resc) this has been a bug for a long long time now.